# Error installing PyObjc: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed

Tags: python, macos, pyglet

I've been working on a python script, first using the Psychopy compiler, which already included all I needed, but now I need to make it the more independent as possible. I have the script working on a Windows computer, but I also want it to work in OSX.

The script uses pyglet and I followed [this post](http://twistedpairdevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/installing-pyglet-in-mac-os-x/) in order to install it. However, when I reach the latest step, which is installing PyObjc, I have the following error:

```
40 warnings and 1 error generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/fk/1plt8wj53_d183pv59scmg4m0000gn/T/pip_build_JL/pyobjc-core/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/fk/1plt8wj53_d183pv59scmg4m0000gn/T/pip-HfEjaW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fk/1plt8wj53_d183pv59scmg4m0000gn/T/pip_build_JL/pyobjc-core
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/JL/.pip/pip.log
```

Why does this error appears? What can I do to solve it?

Comment: For Apple M1 doubts, see other answers like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66771944/1736679

Answer (score 7):

Terminal post：

```
xcode-select --install
```

may be can help you.

Comment: "40 warnings and 1 error generated." This means `clang` has been installed but failed to compile the code.

Comment: yesterday，when i 'pip install lxml ',the same error occured.
after 'xcode-select --install' ,that/s ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing pyobjc separately first.

On OSX 10.7 or 10.8, try:

```
env CC=clang pip -U pyobjc-core
env CC=clang pip -U pyobjc
```

On OSX 10.9, try:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pyobjc
```

Comment: The latter gives me the following on 10.9:  
warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future'; did you mean '-Werror=unused-command-line-argument'? [-Wunknown-warning-option