# numpy build fail in M1 Big sur 11.1

Tags: python-3.x, macos, numpy

I am using MacBook m1 which is running Big Sur 11.1 ,and I have installed `Xcode-commandline-tools` version 12.3 and it has installed `python3.8.5` and `pip3` .python3 and pip are native apps,that is they run in ARM

`pip3` version `20.3.3`

`python3` version `3.8.5`

`setuptools` version `51.0.0`

`wheel` version `0.36.2`

when I type `python3 -m pip install numpy`

The output is :

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.19.4.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): started
sandeep@Sandeeps-Air ~ % cat a
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.19.4.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build numpy
```

and with a very large list of [errors](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/vr4SWqZdqj/)

Is numpy still not supported in M1 or am I doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 67):

I had exactly the same issue with my brand new Mac Mini. After spending an afternoon [reading this issue on github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17807), I finally succeeded. However, it only seems to work [with v1.20.0rc2](https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git) or above...

Long story short, these were the steps I've taken to get it working:

```
pip3 install Cython
git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git 
cd numpy
pip3 install . --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517
```

After that, I could `cd` into my virtualenv and import numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.21.0.dev0+402.gc4ae3ce64'
>>>
```

Next up: pandas.

*UPDATE:*
After some more searching, I found [this interesting article](https://alexslobodnik.medium.com/apple-m1-python-pandas-and-homebrew-20f14828ccc7), which states that you can easily start Terminal in Rosatta mode. That also solved the issues.

However, I am working with a headless Mac Mini, so I still have to find out whether that solution also is feasable in that particular setup.

*UPDATE 2*

I now have pandas working as well, thanks to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66048187/10974490).

Comment: I had the same issue though a variant of it. I was installing numpy inside docker (preview for M1). The steps here were helpful to point me in a direction. I needed a specific version of numpy installed so after cloning I checkout out the version I needed `git checkout v1.xx.x` and went ahead to install.

Comment: slight variant: skipping the git download, I just directly did `pip3 install --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517 numpy` and it works for me

Comment: For `Python 3.9.5` & `pip 21.1.2`, git-download method didn't work but the the skipping method that @CrepeGoat  suggests worked fine! Great.

Comment: Thanks!!! The one-liner is pip install git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517

Comment: `ERROR: Disabling PEP 517 processing is invalid: project does not have a setup.py`

Answer (score 20):

Yes, numpy still seems to be not supported in stable, but if you are ready to work with **unstable** version try this command:

```
pip3 install numpy --compile --pre
```

This will recompile all the necessary code from **unstable branch**.

Worked for me.

Comment: This got me closer to anything else I've tried, but I still ended up with `ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`. Aargh!

Comment: Maybe `--no-use-pep517` does the trick? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/

Comment: The --no-use-pep517 option didn't work for me and I got the same result as John Laundun.

Comment: It worked for me. I think the issue is that you should use the default xcode cli python. The version at this time is 3.8

Comment: This isn't working for me! It says the same thing whatever I do! `ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`. I'm using Python v3.9, and nothing's working!

Comment: @MikhailKaravashkin, I tried that, and now it's logging another error: ```ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/numpy.js/env/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/d_/gv1n_nvn2f99dqd7kf7vc3xw0000gn/T/pip-install-gu24p82c/numpy_c325c47fa8b44d88bed196c1ebd4edca/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/d_/gv1n_nvn2f99dqd7kf7vc3xw0000gn/T/pip-install-gu24p82c/numpy_c325c47fa8b44d88bed196c1ebd4edca/setup.py'"'"';f = ```...

Comment: ...```getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/d_/gv1n_nvn2f99dqd7kf7vc3xw0000gn/T/pip-record-v_5waeaf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/numpy.js/env/include/site/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command output.```

Answer (score 12):

Since NumPy 1.21.0, it has released **universal2** wheels for Python 3.8 and Python 3.9 on Mac. It becomes installable on Mac M1.

I have tested it on my M1 with Python 3.9.2, macOS Big Sur (11.5.1), and pip 21.1.3. Just use `pip/pip3` to install it.

release note: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.21.0

Comment: My M1 came with Python 3.8.9 installed and it failed to build numpy. Installing Python 3.9.10 via Homebrew fixed it.

Comment: It failed for me on the first time. I tried it again and it downloaded numpy instead of compiling it and it succeeded. Also works with pyenv on 3.8 and 3.9. pyenv with 3.12 still fails.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the only reliable build environment for the full data-science suite for python at the moment (Feb 2021) on M1 ARM architecture is via miniforge.

e.g.

```
brew install --cask miniforge
conda init zsh
conda activate
conda install numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

Comment: Thanks this is the only thing that worked for me. I am using the VScode M1 insiders build and setting my interpreter to where miniforge is got all these working.

Answer (score 5):

What it worked for me was to run iTerm with the option "open using Rosetta" enabled and upgrade pip before installing numpy.

[image]

Instead of enabling this option you could also run the `pip install` and python selecting a different architecture with `arch -x86_64`. Example using a virtual environment:

```
$ python3 -m venv ~/myenv
$ source ~/myenv/bin/activate
(myenv)$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-20.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.3
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1

(myenv)$ arch -x86_64 pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.20.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (16.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.20.1

(myenv)$ arch -x86_64 python3
Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:44:01)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.20.1'
```

Comment: Wanted to leave a comment that this was the only one which worked for M1. Specifically, setting Terminal to open in Rosetta, `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`, and lastly `arch -x86_64 pip install numpy`

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to install numpy without rosetta 2, but the solutions listed here failed for me. Brew saved the day. I installed it with

```sh
brew install numpy
```

Comment: This did the trick for me too. In case it matters, I have `python@3.9` installed via `brew`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this as I was able to install numpy using this method.

1. `brew install openblas` (use the native homebrew instead of running it under Rosetta 2)
2. `OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" pip3 install numpy`

Comment: this didn't work for me, fails with error 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/gz/p5bntj6n0tsbwm355mj3gb640000gn/T/tmpn9lk223d Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Try using the command line tools installed python 3.8 instead of the brew installed python 3.9

Answer (score 2):

First of all numpy support is not there for m1 arm based Macs using python 3.8 version. The method to workaround with this is to update your python version to 3.9. This is the latest version of python and can be a bit unstable. If you want to work with tensorflow then do not update to python 3.9 version as they don't support it and support will come up with version 2.5 (estimated). So, if you don't want to use tensorflow and want to use numpy by using pip install then go ahead install python3.9 and make it your default python interpreter.

I will recommend you to use Homebrew for installation of python 3.9 as it as easy as running a simple command.

Comment: could you add links to documentation that support what you are saying, please?

Comment: Yes, so for my tensorflow response please follow this thread https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44485
Checking the working of numpy was coincidence as python3.9 got installed for a package for me and then I tried installing numpy and it worked.

You can surely look for other solutions for installing numpy without help of wheel by downloading and installing it from source(that should work but I am not sure).

Answer (score 2):

faced the same problem in monterey too.

upgrading pip version to 21.3.1 from 20.2.3 solved the issue.

```
source env/bin/activate
pip install -U pip
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for pipenv users:

```
git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git --recursive
cd numpy
pip3 install build
python3 -m build
cd dist
cp numpy-1.22.0.dev0+97.g4635fc852-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl ../../ # filename is current sample, next folder to your project directory
```

Add into Pipfile:

```
[packages]
numpy = { path = "numpy-1.22.0.dev0+97.g4635fc852-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl" }
```

```
pipenv install
```

then your numpy will be installed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a previous answer, the installation went smooth when I opened the terminal using Rosetta.

However for anyone who is using Pycharm terminal, Do the following to get the terminal running using Rosetta.

- Go to Preferences -> Tools -> Terminal
- Update the script path to "env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login"

I tried a lot of other options but so far this was the simplest solution I found.

Comment: i highly recommend working hard enough to not use rosetts manually....

Answer (score 0):

After trying a ton of suggested methods I finally found a way to use numpy on my new macbook pro with an M1 chip.

Use [this docker preview](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/) for the M1 chip.

E.g. here's a Dockerfile that successfully installs numpy.

```
FROM python

RUN python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Build it with:

```
docker build -t numpytest:latest .
```

Then run it with:

```
docker run -it --rm numpytest:latest
```

And you can verify that numpy is installed and works correctly:

```
Python 3.9.1 (default, Jan 12 2021, 13:13:57) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess it's fixed in unreleased upstream.  A pip install of 1.20.2, the latest as of this writing, failed.  But I cloned git@github.com:numpy/numpy.git, then did the normal "python setup.py install" in my venv (which is Python 3.9.5 installed via Homebrew) and it seems to work.  Haven't thoroughly tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

CrepeGoat's comment worked for me:

```
pip3 install --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517 numpy
```