# How to install and import Scipy, Numpy, NumExpr and others on M1 (Apple Silicon / Darwin-arm64)?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, apple-m1

I have an M1 processor from Apple, which is a new ARM64 architecture, and the binaries provided for many data science Python packages will not run on it, and compiling them fails in most cases.

Questions such as [How to install SciPy on Apple Silicon (ARM / M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65745683/how-to-install-scipy-on-apple-silicon-arm-m1) or [numpy build fail in M1 Big sur 11.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65336789/numpy-build-fail-in-m1-big-sur-11-1) offer many different answers, some of which work and most don't. However, even for those that manage to make the modules compile, I don't understand how I can make `pip` install my locally compiled packages instead of fetching them (and failing) from pypy.

How can I install `numpy`, `scipy`, `numexpr` and others as a dependency on a computer with an M1 processor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install Miniforge with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to compile these modules locally: `brew install miniforge`.
2. Install the modules you need with `conda` instead of `pip`: `conda install numpy` (and `scipy`, `numexpr`…).
3. In the environment in which you install your dependencies (global, user or virtual environment with `venv`, `pew` or similar), install as you would usually, but let your package manager know to load these native modules you installed earlier by defining [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables): prefix the install command with `PYTHONPATH=/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/:$PYTHONPATH`. For example: `PYTHONPATH=/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs/:$PYTHONPATH pip3 install`.

Comment: When will it just work with pip? without Conda.