# How to install SciPy on MacOS with M1

Tags: python, keras, scipy

I am trying to install keras in a virtual env but was getting errors. I then tried to install it following the steps on this site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/keras/keras_installation.htm. The first few installs work but when I ran `pip install SciPy` I kept getting errors. I found others have  encountered issues with installing SciPy on apple silicon online and saw a few recommendations but haven't been able to get anything to work so far. Can anyone help me out? Will I just have to wait for SciPy to release a compatible version?

If its helpful, I am working on a M1 processor with MacOS 11.3.1, and using python 3.8.2.

I have tried using homebrew as outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66536896/16461391.

I have tried using miniforge as outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66768260/16461391.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install SciPy on Apple Silicon (ARM / M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65745683/how-to-install-scipy-on-apple-silicon-arm-m1)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to do it. I'm just posting my answer here in case someone else is stuck on the problem.

The way I did it was by running in terminal:
`conda install -c conda-forge keras`
then I checked it was installed in my condo env using the anaconda navigator, then I opened the condo environment in pycharm by following the steps here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html.