# Install pandas on Mac M1 Big Sur into multiple virtualenv

Tags: python, pandas, pip, apple-m1

Like many others I was not able to install (using pip) pandas on my MacBook M1, eventually thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66048187/9095551) I managed to install it from source.
After cloning pandas the steps are

```
source venv/bin/activate
pip install cython
cd pandas
python3 setup.py install
```

I am obviously able to do the same for every project (virtualenv) I work with, but I would like to install in each project the locally built pandas module (v1.3.0.dev0+1019.gc10dd1a5f1) without a full rebuild from source.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `python3 setup.py install` run `pip wheel .`, save the wheel from `dist/` folder and next time install from the wheel:

```
pip install /path/to/pandas.whl
```

Comment: Run `pip wheel .` didnt work, got a lot of errors ('clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec')' but `python setup.py bdist_wheel` did the job creating a .whl file. What is the difference?

Comment: Shouldn't be that much. You can try `pip wheel -vvv .` to see what `pip` is doing.

Comment: No luck, still lots of compilation error. I tried the same on a different module (requests) and `pip wheel` does not fail but it does not create the dist folder with the .whl file

Comment: My fault. The wheel(s) are created in the current directory, not in `dist/`.

Comment: Yes, I see now in the root `requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`. Pandas still no luck, I will try to grab the whole output log (now truncated by PyCharm terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code

```
 brew install openblas

 pip3 install cython

 OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" pip3 install numpy --no-use-pep517

 OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" pip3 install pandas --no-use-pep517
```