# Use Pandas under VSCODE on M1 Macbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, macos, apple-m1

I just managed to correctly install pandas on my M1 MacBook Pro following the recommended way here : [Trouble installing Pandas on new MacBook Air M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084318/trouble-installing-pandas-on-new-macbook-air-m1).

I also have downloaded the specific version of VSCODE for Apple M1 chip.

The issue I have now is that the integrated terminal inside VSCODE is NOT running under **Rosetta 2** (equivalent to the native Terminal app on MacOS before using the option **Open Using Rosetta**). I know that I can use VSCODE with a external Terminal, but I'd rather find a solution to use the integrated terminal in VSCODE, if possible.

Comment: not sure about vscode, but what would the recommended way be? there are plenty of methods listed in those answers, I'm using pandas without issues in a normal pip installation (python installed with brew); conda miniforge also works pretty fine.

Comment: @filippo thanks for your answer. What I would like is to take fully advantage of VSCode, using its built-in functionalities (terminal / debugger / etc...) but some python librairies are not yet supported on M1 MacBooks such as Pandas. It's annoying for me as I'm a data scientist relying a lot on this library. I already have a working solution, using external terminal, but that's not optimal

Comment: cannot help you with VSCode but I use pandas everyday on M1, installed with `python3 -m pip install pandas --no-use-pep517` (some other data science libraries work better with conda miniforge)

Comment: @filippo thanks a lot for your help, it worked ! I just had to install the following `pip3 install cython pybind11`  before and it worked perfectly after that !

Comment: Are you getting an error with VScode or you just odn't see a terminal? ctrl + ` opens a terminal. maybe this video will help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNnq8h-UCJE

Comment: @BrandonKauffman Thanks for your answer, my issue was that the integrated terminal inside VSCode is not running under Rosetta 2 (which supports Pandas). With the help of @filippo I managed to install Pandas inside the VSCode interpreter by installing python with brew, then `pip3 install cython pybind11` `pip3 install numpy --no-use-pep517` and finally `pip3 install pandas --no-use-pep517`