# how to install pandas on m1 Mac

Tags: python, pandas, macos, pycharm, apple-m1

```
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/python -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/lib -Ipandas/_libs/src/datetime -I/Users/jesse/Desktop/ssc/pythonProject3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/jesse/Desktop/ssc/pythonProject3/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/ujson.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/ujson.o -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-unused-function
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=0 -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/python -Ipandas/_libs/src/ujson/lib -Ipandas/_libs/src/datetime -I/Users/jesse/Desktop/ssc/pythonProject3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Users/jesse/Desktop/ssc/pythonProject3/venv/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.o -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-unused-function
    pandas/_libs/src/ujson/python/objToJSON.c:181:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL'
        return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL;
               ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/jesse/Desktop/ssc/pythonProject3/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ky/s4qqls154f9c4j5lfcfspbpm0000gn/T/pip-install-t5zlzk09/pandas_67e63708ec954c589e697c9f10e3730c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ky/s4qqls154f9c4j5lfcfspbpm0000gn/T/pip-install-t5zlzk09/pandas_67e63708ec954c589e697c9f10e3730c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/ky/s4qqls154f9c4j5lfcfspbpm0000gn/T/pip-record-cnus0d48/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/jesse/Desktop/ssc/pythonProject3/venv/include/site/python3.8/pandas Check the logs for full command output.
(base)
```

I want to download pandas on Mac mini using PyCharm.

What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

This was answered on:

[Trouble installing Pandas on new MacBook Air M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084318/trouble-installing-pandas-on-new-macbook-air-m1)

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3.8 venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy cython
git clone https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git
cd pandas
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I needed to install an extra lib (versioneer) and after installing pandas still can't be used cause of import error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.pandas_parser'`

Answer (score 1):

You have to have `numpy` installed in your environment to build `pandas` from source for all versions of `pandas` that come without a `pyproject.toml`. Please install `numpy` first and try again.

---

If `numpy` is installed on your machine you may need to update the version using `pip install numpy -U` or an equivalent command executed via PyCharm GUI.

Comment: This helped me. Uninstalling numpy followed by installing pandas (therby updating numpy) solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

While caeneb's trick worked like a charm, I found that upgrading your python to a later version and updating pip worked as well.

for me these where the commands that did the trick (I manage my python installation with `pyenv`)

```sh
pyenv install 3.9.9
pyenv global 3.9.9 # use this python version as the default
pip install pandas # just works
```

I guess that without pyenv you can simply run the following commands (untested)

```sh
brew install python@3.9.9
$(brew --prefix)/bin/python3.9 -m pip install pandas # makes sure to use the right pip
```

Comment: Why does this work though?

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but it might have something to do with latest releases of pandas only being available on newer python versions. ([increased minimum version for python](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#increased-minimum-version-for-python)).

Answer (score 1):

From manually reviewing the numpy git log, downgrading numpy using
`pip install numpy==1.18.5` and then

`OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.4 pip3 install pandas==0.25.3 --no-use-pep517`

After installation of pandas, I was able to upgrade numpy again

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `conda`, so that you can install virtual environments, also with different python version and eventually with different R (and also node.js). Much simpler and programs are pre-compiled (and conda was created for such cases).

Else, are you sure you have `xcode` installed? Check on Apple store. Xcode is the "SDK" (developer toolkit) of Apple with the compiler: the `clang`: you doesn't have it, so the error. It gives you also other tools which are generally needed for pip. Note: you should also execute manually also one xcode command, to be able to accept the xcode condition (else you may have problem on scripts which uses xcode).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
`pip install git+git://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git`

Answer (score -3):

$`pip install pandas`

For installing pip in Mac :

`$curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

OR

- Install python with homebrew:

  `brew install python`
- Make sure of correct path:

  `$which python`
- Now install pandas:

  `$pip install pandas`

Comment: this solution does not solve the problem in question due to the specific nature of  M1 (Apple Silicon) which is ARM and not Intel architecture.