# Troubles installing Pandas on Mac Book Pro with M1 procesor

Tags: pandas, apple-m1

I switched from Windows NTB to MacBook Pro with M1. And I am not able to install Pandas, some issue with missing wheel for numpy. I am using Python 3.9. I went through various solutions presented here like this one below, but none work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66048187/16324084
This one was one of the most explanatory, but I went through all steps, but when I run some code I will get this error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'.
As I am new with Apple, no idea what is conda or roseta, so please can somebody write me what I should do to get Pandas installed and working? And please try to explain it as a small child, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install Anaconda, a package manager. Instructions [here](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). I have all of my packaged managed through this on my Big Sur m1 silicone MacBook pro and have not had issues since switching over from Intel.

Once you have installed anaconda, open terminal and run:

```
conda install pandas
```

More info on using anaconda [here](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, conda installed, I am able to use at least JupyterNotebook with conda, so that is great, that now I can work with Python and Pandas on my Mac. But when I tried to install pandas using conda install pandas in terminal in VS Code I received message: # All requested packages already installed.And when I tried to run some Python code with Pandas I get back this message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "pandas". No idea where could be the issue, only that in Anaconda was mentioned Python 3.8 and I am using Python 3.9. And is it ok that I see in terminal: (venv) (base) myusername?