# Install Scikit-Learn Big Sur M1

Tags: macos, scikit-learn

There seems to be an issue installing scikit-learn on Mac M1 chips for Big Sur. I tried including the environment variable flags in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68620927/installing-scipy-and-scikit-learn-on-apple-m1) to no avail.

The specific error is:

```sh
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.0.2.tar.gz (6.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5382 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
...clip...
Running from SciPy source directory.
            /private/var/folders/4s/pdgwwvsn2wd9192jdyz2lk8w0000gn/T/pip-install-7gy3iln3/scipy_92a96fbb9138448d8d153c3fef5c5cb4/scipy/linalg/_generate_pyx.py:674: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
...clip...
libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
              libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
              NOT AVAILABLE
            openblas_lapack_info:
            C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -falign-functions=8
            creating /var/folders/4s/pdgwwvsn2wd9192jdyz2lk8w0000gn/T/tmpqd0a75ee/var
            creating /var/folders/4s/pdgwwvsn2wd9192jdyz2lk8w0000gn/T/tmpqd0a75ee/var/folders
...clip...
```