# pip install on M1 mac: No matching distribution found for version when version actually exists

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install pandas 1.2.5 but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.2.5 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0, 0.3.0b2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.25.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.3.0, 1.3.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.2.5
```

As you can see the version I'm looking for is listed in the available versions. Does anyone know why I can't install it?

I'm using this command and my env is macOS:

```
pip install pandas==1.2.5
```

My python version is 3.8 and my pip version is 21.2.3

Comment: no, the `==` is correct

Comment: No with `pandas=1.2.5` I get `ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'pandas=1.2.5'`

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have a conflicting requirement? Like some other dependency requiring an incompatible version of `pandas`? I think when that's the case you get this kind of error message.

Comment: Try listing available versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available

Comment: `pip` may be a different version of python. Type `which pip` to see. Can force it to run with the desired python installation by running `python3.8 -m pip`.

Comment: @Ghoti interesting, it only lists the latest version `1.3.1`. But why?

Comment: Same error with forcing python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have pandas already installed? You can at least try

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.2.5
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade pandas==1.2.5
```

to "downgrade" pandas

Comment: I don't have any other version of pandas installed.

Comment: I've downgraded and upgraded at this point from 1.3.0 -> 1.2.5 -> 1.3.1 using macOS, python 3.9.1 and pip 21.2.3, so the problem is certainly on your end. You may need to reinstall pip itself.

Comment: Reinstalled pip but still the same error :'( I'm using an M1 mac, not sure that has to do anything with it.

Comment: So i did some digging, and yes, it appears that M1 mac's are having problems with pip. I'll add some links to articles, and let me know if they are helpful. Seems useful to do this research now as i probably need to upgrade myself here in the next year or two:

https://gist.github.com/MohamedElashri/25c3999df42da201b8819d8bb811a5e4

and

https://flutterq.com/pip-install-matplotlib-fails-on-m1-mac/

and finally, a very similar problem to yours without downgrading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084318/trouble-installing-pandas-on-new-macbook-air-m1

Comment: thanks for sharing these articles, makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try `pip install -Iv pandas==1.2.5` or `pip install -I pandas==1.2.5`

have u already installed pandas before?

Comment: Still same error with the above suggestion, and no I don't have other versions of pandas installed.

Comment: weird, have u tried installing pandas without giving a version and what error message appears there? so just `pip install pandas`?

Comment: I can install the latest version `1.3.1`

Comment: weird. try installing it on a virtualenv maybe. so:
`pip install virtualenv`
`virtualenv <somename>`
`source <somepath>`
`pip install pandas==1.2.5`